# Web2py MySQL database reference error

Tags: python, mysql, web2py, data-access-layer

I'm using web2py with a MySQL database. The database scheme in my db.py file looks like the following:

```
db.define_table('app',
                 Field('name'),
                 Field('appdomain')
               )

db.define_table('role_group',
                 Field('appid', db.app),
                 Field('name')
               )

db.define_table('user',
                Field('userid', required=True),
                Field('name', required=True),
                primarykey=['userid'])

db.define_table('role',
                 Field('appid', db.app),
                 Field('role_group', db.role_group),
                 Field('name')
               )

db.define_table('role_authorization',
                 Field('userid', db.user, required=True),
                 Field('roleid', db.role, required=True),
                 primarykey=['userid', 'roleid']
               )

db.define_table('group_authorization',
                 Field('userid', db.user),
                 Field('groupid', db.role_group),
                 primarykey=['userid', 'groupid']
               )
```

When I run the following query:

```
userid = "fb|1234"
userAuthorizations = db((db.user.userid == userid)
                                & (db.tetra_user.userid == db.role_authorization.userid)
                                & (db.role_authorization.roleid == db.role.id)
                                & (db.role.appid == db.app.id)
                            ).select()
```

It returns this error: ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: 'fb|1234'. 
I hope someone knows what causes this error and can help me to solve it.

Kind regards,
Simon

Comment: Why are you using `primarkey`? That's rarely needed and only used to support legacy databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to set migrate to False in the legacy tables. So web2py won't intent to change them.

Second, try to specify the type of the field `userid` because the such error happens when you try to cast "fb|1234" to an integer:

```
>>> int("fb|1234") 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'fb|1234'
```